# Balancing grid item size and center alignment for responsive browsers

Tags: css, flexbox, responsive-design, css-grid

I am setting up a menu using grid with the intention of it being responsive and centered on page.  There are two items in the grid, a hex menu (made with flex) and an image.  These overlap with each other such that the image(right) aligns with the center of the hex menu (left). I'm struggling to get the height of both items to be equal at all times while keeping the entire thing centered while being responsive.
[here is the layout with grid turned on in chrome inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V03jI.png)

```
:root{
  /* Colors */
  --color-hex-default: #ffffff;
  --color-hex-hover: #ffffff;
  }

.hexcontainer {

  display: grid;
  grid-auto-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}


.hexmenu {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1/3;
  z-index: 3;
  justify-self: center;
}
.notcat {
  background-image: url(/notcat1400.jpg);
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 2 / 4;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(to right, transparent 2%, black 25%);
  background-size: contain;
  z-index: 1;
    height: 100%;
}

.hexGrid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0 0 -1.75% 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: "Nunito Sans";
  font-weight: bold;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0px;
}
ul.hexGrid {
  width:20vw;
  position:relative;
  padding-top: 100%

}

li.hexGrid {
  --h: calc(100% / 3);
  --w: calc(1.15470053838 * var(--h));
  --a: calc(0.28867513459 * var(--h));
  --d: calc(0.57735026919 * var(--h));
  height:var(--h);
  width:var(--w);
  position:absolute;
font-size: 1.25vw;
}


.hexLink {

    background-color: var(--color-hex-default);
    color: white; /*text in hex before color*/
    overflow: hidden;
        transition: background-color 0.4s ease;
        display:block;
        width:95%;
        height:95%;
        --aw:24.99999999999%;
        clip-path:polygon(
          var(--aw) 0,
          0 50%,
          var(--aw) 100%,
          calc(100% - var(--aw)) 100%,
          100% 50%,
          calc(100% - var(--aw)) 0
        );
}

.hexLink.color-contact {
  color:black;
  }

li:nth-of-type(1) {
  left:calc(50% - var(--a) - var(--d) * 0.5);
  top:0;
}
li:nth-of-type(2) {
  left:calc(50% - var(--a) * 2 - var(--d) * 1.5);
  top:calc(var(--h) * 0.5);
}
li:nth-of-type(3) {
  left:calc(50% - var(--a) * 2 - var(--d) * 1.5);
  top:calc(var(--h) * 1.5);
}
li:nth-of-type(4) {
  left:calc(50% - var(--a) - var(--d) * 0.5);
  top:calc(var(--h) * 2);
}
li:nth-of-type(5) {
  left:calc(50% + var(--d) * 0.5);
  top:calc(var(--h) * 0.5);
}
li:nth-of-type(6) {
  left:calc(50% + var(--d) * 0.5);
  top:calc(var(--h) * 1.5);
}
li:nth-of-type(7) {
  position:absolute;
  left:calc(50% - var(--a) - var(--d) * 0.5);
  top:calc(var(--h) * 1.0);

}

hext {
margin: 0;
position: absolute;
text-align: center;
top: 47.5%;
left: 47.5%;
/*font-size: 2vw;*/
-o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    font-weight: bold;
    word-break: keep-all;
}
hext:hover{
transition: 0.1s;
}

.hexLink:hover {
  background-color: var(--color-hex-hover);
  transition: 0.2s ease;
}
.hexLink.color-contact:hover{
  background-color: black;
}
.hexLink:hover::after,
.hexLink:hover::before {
  border-top-color: var(--color-hex-hover);
  border-bottom-color: var(--color-hex-hover);
}
```

```
    <div class="hexcontainer">
<div class="hexmenu">
<ul class="hexGrid">
<li class="hexGrid"><a class="hexLink color-design" href="#"><hext>design</hext></a></li>
<li class="hexGrid"><a class="hexLink color-blog" href="#"><hext>blog</hext></a></li>
<li class="hexGrid"><a class="hexLink color-workshop" href="#"><hext>workshop</hext></a></li>
<li class="hexGrid"><a class="hexLink color-teach" href="#"><hext>coach</hext></a></li>
<li class="hexGrid"><a class="hexLink color-coach" href="#"><hext>teach</hext></a></li>
<li class="hexGrid"><a class="hexLink color-about" href="#"><hext>about</hext></a></li>
<li class="hexGrid"><a class="hexLink color-contact" href="#"><hext>contact</hext></a></li>
</ul></div>
<div class="notcat">
    </div>
</div>
```